Scheduled trigger Azure DevOps pipeline checking for [skip ci] in commits
What is the correct syntax to set an Azure DevOps pipeline to be triggered at a scheduled time, but only if (at least) one commit was pushed to a specific branch, excluding those tagged with [skip ci]?
This is my current configuration, but it's running every night. I assume it is because this pipeline pushes some commits to the triggering branch, but they have the [skip ci] prefix in the comment which, according to the documentation, should prevent the pipeline from triggering.
trigger: none

schedules:
  - cron: "0 0 * * *"
    displayName: 'Nightly Build'
    branches:
      include:
        - mybranch


"You can also tell Azure Pipelines to skip running a pipeline that a push would normally trigger" - this build isn't normally triggered by a push.

I thought this would count since the scheduled run wouldn't trigger without a push (the parameter always is false by default), and I assumed it used the same logic of normal triggers, taking into consideration the skip ci tag. Do you know any way to exclude those commits?

This looks like a question for https://devops.stackexchange.com/

Check alway parameters: Scheduled triggers.
trigger: none

schedules:
  - cron: "0 0 * * *"
    displayName: 'Nightly Build'
    branches:
      include:
        - mybranch
    always: false

[skip ci] will not have any impact here because it is only for continuous integration

If a pipeline is triggered by a commit pushed onto a branch of the repo, the Build.Reason for this pipeline run is IndividualCI.
While it is triggered by the cron schedule, the Build.Reason for such pipeline runs is Schedule.
To include [skip ci] in the message will only skip CI for individual pushes and will not prevent the schedule trigger.
Besides, the always: boolean in the cron syntax is used to control whether to always run the pipeline or only if there have been source code changes since the last successful scheduled run.
I do understand your expectations, since the pushes skipped for a CI may usually need to be skipped for a schedule trigger as well. However, I fear that as of now there is no message that we can pass in a commit to prevent a schedule trigger. For this, you may create a feature request via: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?space=21&entry=suggestion . That will allow you to directly interact with the appropriate Product Group, and make it more convenient for the product group to collect and categorize your suggestions.
